# Prove $C(x) = \Pi C(x_{\mu})$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X_{\mu}, \tau_{\mu})_{\mu \in M}$ a family of topological spaces, if $x \in (\Pi X_{\mu}, \tau)$, $\tau$ is product topological. Prove $C(x) = \Pi C(x_{\mu})$.

We define $C(x)$ as union of all subspaces connected of $(X,\tau)$ which has $x$. But how could you define $\Pi C(x_{\mu})$?

Comment: $C(x_\mu)$ is the component in $X_\mu$ of $x_\mu$. So $\prod C(x_\mu)$ is the topological product of these components which is a topological subspace of $\prod X_\mu$,

Comment: Do you know that any product of connected spaces is connected? And likewise for continuous images? It follows from that.